# Increasing integer after having found occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I have a text with several occurrences of websites, let's say "www.test.com". I want to replace all these occurrences by "website_NR", where NR should start at 1.

Example:

```
text = "bbsjsddh www.test.com shduh sudhuhd sjdjsdh wiowqiuedl www.test.de uasuisdhckjdfh www.test.de sudhdhdhfh"
```

Now, every occurrence of "www.test.com" should be replaced by "website_1", "website_2", and so on...

I tried it with:

```
n = 0
if 'www.test.com' in text:
        n = n+1
text = text.replace('www.test.com', 'website_'+str(n))
```

But...this method counts only the first occurrence of "www.test.com"

Comment: Well... if you want to do something more than once, you're going to need to write a loop.

Comment: .count gives you the amout of occurrences (n), then replace n times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code function below will replace `old` with `new + '_{}'.format(n)` one at a time while `old` is in your string. It also increases `n` for each iteration so you get 'website_1', 'website_2', etc.

```
def func(s, old, new):
    n = 1
    while old in s:
        s = s.replace(old, new + '_{}'.format(n), 1)
        n += 1

    return s

text = "bbsjsddh www.test.com shduh sudhuhd sjdjsdh wiowqiuedl www.test.com uasuisdhckjdfh www.test.com sudhdhdhfh"

print(func(text, 'www.test.com', 'website'))
# bbsjsddh website_1 shduh sudhuhd sjdjsdh wiowqiuedl website_2 uasuisdhckjdfh website_3 sudhdhdhfh
```